# position image at the bottom of the screen, the entire width with a thin margin

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am trying to put an image on the bottom of the screen and I want the width of the button to always be the entire screen minus a thin margin.

My screen is made up of 3 parts, a View at the top, a ScrollView in the middle and the button on the bottom.  They all live in a view called container.

Container has flex 8, and the two other views have flex 1 and flex 5 respectively.

The image at the bottom lives in a view of it's own.

```
imageView: {
  flex:2,
},
Image: {
  margin:1,
},
```

I have tried a bunch of things, for styling including resizeMode contain, and other things to try get it to work but i just can't get the effect that I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful if you could post your render method and styling here but this can generally be achieved by using position: 'absolute' style property. bottom: 0 would mean it will stick to bottom and left: 1 and right: 1 will give it a margin of 1 on both sides.

```
  bottomImage: {
  position: 'absolute',
  bottom: 0,
  right: 1,
  left: 1,
  height: 50,
},
```